# Extra Space For Jade

Tags: pug

```
h1= task.title

div!= task.body


form(method="Post", action="/tasks/edit/"+encodeURIComponent(task.title))
  p
    label(for="title") Title<br />
    input#title(name="title", value =task.title) 


  p
    label(for="body") Body<br />
    textarea#body(name="body")  
     =task.body

  p
    input(type="submit", value="Create")
```

This one of my jade.template. Now, I don't understand why there's an extra space in the text area right before the value inside the textbox. In the picture, there's a space before "task" in the text box and I've been trying to get rid of it.

[image: HTML output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jade does not add whitespace that isn't explicitly defined in strings (e.g. `=" task"`), so it must be in the `task.body` variable.

Perhaps trim it before outputting it:

```jade
textarea#body(name="body")  
  = task.body.trim()
```